# Multiple input parameters for the method execute() of AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

everyone. I have read on the android site the description of the excute() of AsyncTask:

`public final AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> execute (Params... params)`

But within my project, I have read the code like this:

```
private static final int JSON = 0;
private static final int NAME = 1;
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strData) {    
       FileOutputTask task = new FileOutputTask(context);
       task.execute(strData[JSON], strData[NAME]);
}
```

Somebody can tell me why there are **2 input parameters** for the **execute()** method?

Since according the specification, there should be only one input parameter.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Read `Params... params` as `Params[] params`. You can send as many params as you want.

Comment: how would one access the Params [] params when invoking doInBackground()?

Comment: got it: 

passing multiple doInBackground(String... params):
task.execute(uri, username, password, etc...);

getting:
return Login.getResponseXML(params[0], params[1], params[2], etc...);

duh

Answer (score 44):

Here is how I got it to pass multiple parameters.  You could do it as Boris described, but what if you pass different types?

First, create your AsyncTask as normal, but within it, create a constructor:

```
    private class StartTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Boolean> 
    {
        private ProgressDialog progress;
        private String strAction="";

        public StartTask(ProgressDialog progress, String Action)
        {
            this.progress = progress;
            this.strAction = Action;
        }
    }
```

Now, on your event or anything else, when you want to kick off the action you call your AsyncTask and pass as many parameters as you want.

```
    ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress.setMessage("Loading...");
    String strAction = "this_is_a_string";
    new StartTask(progress, strAction).execute(this);
```

You can see that calling "StartTask" and passing the constuctor parameters will now assign the variables within the StartTask class.

Comment: Interesting stuff I must say