# Android : Touch events in layout after animation

Tags: android, animation, touch, android-linearlayout, user-interaction

I have a LinearLayout which contains only a ListView. LinearLayout fills the entire screen and the listView at first stays at the bottom quarter of the screen. **I am setting Top Margin of ListView to a big value to keep the listView at the bottom of the screen**. Below illustration might  help you to understand my layout better.

[image]

Now **on a button click I want my listView to slide up and fill the screen.** I am using Translate animation just like this

```
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.0f
                                ,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f
                                ,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.0f
                                ,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -0.70f);
animation.setDuration(1000);
animation.setFillAfter(true);
animation.setFillEnabled(true); 
mBottomView.startAnimation(animation);
```

where mBottomView is my Listview Layout. And this code successfully animates the listView to the top.

Now my problem is when listView fills the screen, and I try to scroll, touch events to the listview is not recognized above listview's original position. ie when I touch anywhere in the yellow space (in the image) to scroll the listView, touch is not getting detected. I am able to scroll below the listView's original position. Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced same problem and the answer to this problem is completely defined in the answer of this question.
[EditText stucks after animation and alive back on scrolling......?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824079/edittext-stucks-after-animation-and-alive-back-on-scrolling)